# How to Get Rolling Sum Without Returning NA's

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get the rolling sum of the past N days without including NA's. Using this sample df:

`myVec <- data.frame(myVec = c(7,2,4,5,1,3,2,9))`

I'm aware of the function `rollsumr` using this approach:

```
library(zoo)
rollsumr(myVec$myVec, k = 3, fill = NA)
```

Which yields the following output:
`NA NA 13 11 10  9  6 14` However what I don't want is the leading NA's to take up those spots. I'd like to have the first spot be the first index, and second spot be 1st + 2nd, and so on until the `Nth` spot is reached which looks like `7 9 13 11 10  9  6 14` as a final result.

I have a way to iterate through using a for loop if my `N` days was small, however if my rolling sum `N` were to be 50 with 100 rows, I'd have to index individually for each of the first 50 days. So, I'd think there is a simpler, more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `partial=TRUE` in `rollapplyr`:

```
library(zoo)

rollapplyr(myVec$myVec, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)

# [1]  7  9 13 11 10  9  6 14
```

Or using the same function in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

myVec %>%
  mutate(myVec = rollapplyr(myVec, 3, sum, partial = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

`slider::slide_dbl` is what you're looking for.

```
slider::slide_dbl(myVec$myVec, sum,.before = 2, .after = 0)
[1]  7  9 13 11 10  9  6 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient vectorized method in base R:

```
> v=c(7,2,4,5,1,3,2,9)
> o=outer(1:length(v),-2:0,"+")
> rowSums(matrix(v[ifelse(o<1|o>length(v),NA,o)],length(v)),na.rm=T)
[1]  7  9 13 11 10  9  6 14
```

Benchmark:

```
v=sample(1:1e5)

msum=\(x,y){
  o=outer(1:length(x),y,"+")
  rowSums(matrix(x[ifelse(o<1|o>length(x),NA,o)],length(x)),na.rm=T)
}

nonvectorized=\(x,y){
  l=length(x)
  sapply(1:l,\(i)sum(x[max(1,i-y):i],na.rm=T))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=10,
  vectorized=msum(v,-2:0),
  nonvectorized=nonvectorized(v,2),
  rollapplyr=zoo::rollapplyr(v,3,sum,partial=T),
  slide_dbl=slider::slide_dbl(v,sum,.before=2,.after=0)
)
```

```
  Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    vectorized  12.66232  17.63446  17.74140  17.86735  18.41807  25.08393    10
 nonvectorized 154.50835 163.04709 180.35591 172.72742 183.88661 252.43063    10
    rollapplyr 737.47610 789.48767 819.80156 797.42164 820.30966 973.17992    10
     slide_dbl  53.21695  55.42821  61.68474  58.34419  62.53458  83.75196    10
```